# How to remove breaklines when getting text from a JTextArea

Tags: jtextarea

I'm currently building an Instant Messenger program in which the chat history is stored to a database once the chat box is closed. I implemented a method that would retrieve all the text from a chat box and then send it off to a server where it does the whole processing. The chat box contains a JTextArea that contains all the chat two users have had, however whenever I use the getText() method it brings back the entire chat including the break lines,example:-

Guy1: hi there
Guy2: hello
Guy1: well isn't this a shit example
Guy2: yes I know

The way I've set my output stream is by using a Print Writer, so anytime I want to send this message across it has to be sent as a string. However I cannot seem to set that entire conversation to a string variable, it only returns with the first sentence of the conversation. In hindsight I should of used ObjectOutputStreams as it would of made life easier but I just find using print writer easier to use. Does anyone know how to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try using the built in writer that a JTextArea has. 
All JTextComponents have a built in .write() method.

[JTextComponent.write()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/text/JTextComponent.html#write%28java.io.Writer%29)